# Looking for algorithm or a library to generate cool tag clouds (like mirror.me does)

Tags: visualization, data-mining, tag-cloud

Is there algorithms or libraries to generate sexy two-directional tag cloud like mirror.me does. E.g. http://mirror.me/fzmvdr8e

Comment: Well, there should be if it exists ;)

Comment: ha of course I am looking for something I can read and implement without copyright issues etc

Comment: Have you tried dissecting that implementation? **edit** it seems to be serverside

Comment: Yes it is server side, and looks like they draw it using pixel map. This is more complicated than a set of rectangles that do not intersect.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself - there is cool tags cloud visualization library
https://github.com/sschwieb/Cloudio/wiki